# Why if statements blocks in while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have an array of numbers with a bunch of duplicates. I need to get rid of them so  I put the code:

```
  let dup = arr.filter((elem, pos)=> arr.indexOf(elem) !== pos);
  // dup Array contains the duplicate numbers
  arr = arr.filter((elem, pos)=> arr.indexOf(elem) == pos);
  //arr contains the whole array with duplicates
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while(i<arr.length){
    while(j<dup.length){
      if(arr[i] == dup[j]){
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        //the splice method resets the decrease the index of the array so
        i--;
      };
      j++;
    };
    i++
  }
```

The problem is that the if doesn't run after the first match.So the array `splice` the first duplicate that it finds and stops. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm confused.  after your second `filter` the array already has no duplicates. (And the first `filter` is not needed.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I think he wants to get rid of both the numbers that were duplicated. Which he could just do with `arr.filter(x=> dup.indexOf(x) < 0)`. But he is trying to remove it with some convoluted looping

Comment: @James, oh ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @James your answer seems simple and easy. I will replace all my loops with that single line. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set j=0 inside the first while loop, otherwise, it will only run through the second while loop once.

Also, if I were you, I would use a for-loop (array.forEach() specifically) instead of while, because they already count the number of elements anyway.

My solution for this is this:

```
arr.forEach((e, i) => {
    dup.forEach((f, j) => {
        if(e==f){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    })
});
```

Hope it works for you.

EDIT:

Stolen from the comment from James to the original question.
Javascript already provides an easy method to do just that anyway:

```
arr.filter(x=> dup.indexOf(x) < 0)
```

Comment: Yeah. Actually I tried at first whit for loops but It was kind of the same problem so I switched to while lopps hoping it would fix it.

Comment: The advantage here is that you don't need to define the variables you are going through, it's all handled. Probably the shortest and most solid approach. While-loops are tricky, sometimes they don't terminate as you might expect, or in your case, cycle.

Comment: it worked fine. but to solve my problem with removing both duplicates in my array I prefered the answer in the comment to my question which a single line code

Answer (score 3):

From [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

```
const myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];

const unique = [...new Set(myArray)]; 

// output ["a", 1, 2, "1"]
```

or as a function

```
const unique = [...new Set(myArray)]
```

Comment: this doesn't answer his question of why his IF is only hitting once.

Comment: fair point @James, hopefully this suggestion can be used by the OP if it gets the desired outcome.  I am finding it hard to debug his actual code with the multiple while and if statements

Comment: Yeah it's confusing.
I think he wants to get rid of the item that was duplicated too by the way, as he already has the unique items in his `arr` after the second filter. So in your example he'd just want [2]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you never reset `j`.  You need to move that inside the `while (i ...)` loop.

```js
let arr = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]
console.log('arr', arr)

let dup = arr.filter((elem, pos)=> arr.indexOf(elem) !== pos);

console.log('dup', dup)

arr = arr.filter((elem, pos)=> arr.indexOf(elem) == pos)
console.log('new arr', arr)


let i = 0;
while(i<arr.length){
  let j = 0;
  while(j<dup.length){
    if(arr[i] == dup[j]){
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    };
    j++;
  };
  i++
}

console.log('final arr', arr)
```

But there are easier ways to do this.

### Update

I got pinged for mentioning easier ways without showing one.  Here is an alternative way to get the same results:

```js
const singletons = (
  xs,
  dups = xs .filter ((x, i) => arr .indexOf (x) !== i)
) => xs .filter (x => dups .indexOf (x) < 0)

let arr = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]

console .log (
  singletons (arr)
)
```

This version does not modify your original array, just returning a new one containing only the singleton elements (those that appear just once in the original list.)

#### Explanation

`singletons` is a function taking an array of some type of element and returning another array of the same type.  Because that type is not specific, I use a non-specific name; a fairly strong convention make this `xs`. with the `s` noting that it's plural (i.e. an array of them.)

`dups` is an array of elements that is duplicated in your original.  Although I include it as a defaulted parameter, we could just as easily have created it in the body of the function like this:

```js
const singletons = (xs) => {
  const dups = xs .filter ((x, i) => arr .indexOf (x) !== i)
  return xs .filter (x => dups .indexOf (x) < 0)
}
```

The only reason I didn't was that I am perhaps over-fond of single expression bodies, thus avoiding the `{`-`}` pair and the `return` statement.  But there is no real difference between these two approaches, except that the one I presented happens to do some additional work that I would never count on: if you supply a second parameter, an array of values, then, rather than removing the duplicates, it removes all those element from your array that are also in the second one, vaguely reminiscent of a set difference function.

The main advantage of this over your approach is that it is non-destructive.  It does not mutate your original data.  It also has no assignments, except in the default parameter, so there is no confusion in state management.  ("Where do I put `let j == 0`?" is not a meaningful question here.)  This makes it feel more robust.

Comment: Can you tell me what type `singletons` is. What are the parenthesis for. And why xs, dups. Can you just tell me where to learn about it.

Comment: @EyePatch: I added an explanation section.  Short version: this is a fairly standard functional programming approach.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a function 'cause there is an assignment inside the parenthesis. I didn't know such thing is possible.

Comment: @EyePatch: [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) can be very useful for this sort of thing.